# When using git-svn, is there a way to make a commit that 'git svn dcommit' will ignore pushing to its remote?

Tags: git, git-svn

I want to know if there is a way to tell git-svn to ignore a commit in history, and never push it to the remote server.

Comment: If you could, then you wouldn't be able to push any successive commits either, because every git commit depends on its parent commits. What kind of information do you want in the repository which you don't want anyone else to see?

Comment: It's just a set of source files that I would like to have tracked locally that don't get pushed to the remote server. Right now I just copy/paste a backup of these files in the case I need to run "git clean" or anything like that, but "I program, therefore, I am"... lazy haha. I basically want to be able to set my working copy back to any state I need without losing this fileset in question

Comment: If you add those files to your exclude, there's some way for git clean to ignore them, I think. As long as you do not run with -x, they should be fine. You could also place them on a branch and just always rebase it onto master

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that git commands actually honor the .gitignore. For some reason I had the notion that .gitignore just told git not to track those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I could do what I needed by properly configuring my .gitignore file. After more searching, I couldn't find a way to keep specific commits from pushing to the server. And in retrospect, even if you could I can't think of a use case that wouldn't turn your local repository history into spaghetti eventually.